# Shouldn't the questions tagged 'best-practices' be marked as Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Questions about **Best-Practices** are general and can have many acceptable answers.

Shouldn't they be marked as Community Wiki by default?

Comment: Thanks for the flags. I just want to get some feedback from the other mods. on what we consider CW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Community Wiki definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) is all about collaborative editing, and I think the idea is mainly intended for situations where there is no clear or definitive answer. Some "best practices" questions do have a definitive answer; some don't.

In some cases when people say "best practices" they actually mean "my practices". I think the antithesis of "best practices" in this context is "anti-pattern". Both terms are sometimes used by people who just have a strong view.

So I would say that "best practices" is not a strong enough indicator - it depends on whether there is a definitive answer or it is a subject of debate.

Comment: Impressive answer!

Comment: +1 If there is one way to do something the best, then that would be the one answer. If you are polling for best practices, then that question should be closed (or CW).

Comment: +1 .I feel this question :http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12483/migrating-from-sharepoint-2003-to-2010 can have many acceptable answers. In future, many better tools may come up and keep  the post evolving over the time. Shouldn't it be CW? Also this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13400/ntlm-vs-kerberos . The question owner himself commented that he got MANY HELPFUL answers :)

Comment: I really appreciate all your efforts to make the topic clear.I am not sure, but I think I am now still confused over CW. Anyway, I am stopping my nonsense now :). Thanks again to all moderators

Comment: Not at all. Your flags were helpful. Feel free to flag if you see a question that should be a Community Wiki.

Comment: On the NTLM vs. Kerberos question - this is not really a matter of opinion, although the correct choice might depend on the circumstances, and some would say to always go for Kerberos if you can. It is just a case of the questioner choosing the best formulated answer. Therefore I don't think this should be a CW.

Comment: Another thought: If a question is more than a few days old and only has a few answers, I think it is probably not a Community Wiki.